# How can i fetch messages in a dm

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I wanna fetch messages in a dm, like i can in a channel

So i have tried

```js
<user>.messages.fetch(id)
```

But no luck

So what can i do to fetch messages in a dm

Full code

```js
let id = args[0]
let react = args.slice(1).join(' ')

let fetched = message.author.messages.fetch(id)

fetched.react(react)
```

I tried fetching a channel from the id of the author
But also no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`message.author.dmChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/User?scrollTo=dmChannel) to get a [`DMChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/DMChannel) object of the particular user's DMs. Then, you can use [`.messages.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch) to fetch all the messages in the channel, [`.messages.cache.get()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=get) to fetch a message based on its ID or [`.messages.cache.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) to fetch a message based on any property such as its content. An example:

```js
const dmChannel = message.author.dmChannel

const messages = dmChannel.messages.fetch() // This gives you a list of all the message in the channel

const message = dmChannel.messages.cache.get('message-id') // This fetches the message with the particular message id given

const message = dmChannel.messages.cache.find('message-content') // This fetches the message with the particular message content given
```

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please accept it as the correct solution!